# retrieving and displaying data from Firebase into Android app in a listview

Tags: android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hello I want to display strings from my Firebase database into a Listview. I have everything written but I am receiving an error in the line r.setName(...):

```
  private void getUpdates(DataSnapshot ds) {

      programs.clear();

    for (DataSnapshot data : ds.getChildren()) {

        Record r = new Record();
    ---> r.setName(data.getValue(Record.class).getName()); <---

        programs.add(r.getName());

    }...
```

I have these data in my database:[image]

I want to only retrieve whats in "Programs" and print out the 'names'. It's not seem to be working, someone give me some insight and assist please thank you.

Comment: What error you are getting ? and can you show some code about your `FirebaseRef` how you are querying data ?

Answer (score 0):

In your **Record.java** you must declare all variables in your array. ie; you must declare objects for contact,description and name, even if you want to retrieve only name. else error will come if you declared  object only for name.

Comment: I did declare the variables in the array. I got it somewhat working by putting r.setName(data.getValue().toString());  this gives all of the values tho, I only want Name

Comment: create another model class  which has the same objects and getter setter methods like in Record.java and set the name to that class instead of Record.java . this one works for me